# Angular way to fetch checkbox value and the corresponding textbox value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple form where I have a textbox with meaningful names and corresponding to each I have a textbox.

I am able to get the list of checkbox and its ID by following a suggestion but I am not able to get its corresponding textbox value.

Any guidance to achieve this? FYI, the values for the checkbox are from database and iterated through ng-repeat.

Here is the code snippet

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter:search_query">
    <td>
     <label for="{{item.inventoryId}}"> 
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-circle" 
     ng-click="materialSelected(materialSelection.ids, item.inventoryId);"  
     ng-model="materialSelection.ids[item.inventoryId]" name="group" id="
    {{item.inventoryId}}" /> {{item.itemName}}
   </label>
   </td>
   <td><span>
   <label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.requiredQty">                    
   </label></span>
</td>
```

Javascript code

```
$scope.materialSelected = function(idsList, inventoryId) {
                    $scope.materialList = [];
                    var materialId;
                    for (materialId in idsList) {
                        if (idsList[materialId] == true) {
                            $scope.materialList.push({
                                'materialId' : parseInt(materialId, 10)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: can you pls show your code snippet

Comment: I have added the HTML and JS code to my post. Please take a look at it

Comment: @CrazyMac Did you have any luck getting this to work?  Can I help in any other way?

Comment: @TimHarker Thanks for your follow up.. I did something like the one I have posted below and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML element, I add the code below,

```
<span ng-repeat="item itemList" style="text-align: left;"> 
<label for="{{item.itemID}}"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-circle" ng-click="itemSelected(selection.ids, item.itemID)" style="border-radius: 2px;" ng-model="selection.ids[item.itemID]" name="group" id="{{item.itemID}}" /> {{item.itemName}} 
</label> 
</span>
```

In JS, I have to add a function to capture this,

```
function(idsList) {
for (plantID in idsList) {
  if (idsList[plantID] == true) {
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could either try this...

```
$scope.materialList.push({
    'materialId' : parseInt(materialId, 10),
    'requiredQty' : $scope.itemList.find(x => x.inventoryId == materialId).requiredQty
});
```

Or this...

```
$scope.materialList.push({
    'materialId' : parseInt(materialId, 10),
    'requiredQty' : $scope.itemList.filter(function(v) { return v.inventoryId == materialId; })[0].requiredQty
});
```

Depending on browser support needed.